# How to implement record_evaluation callback in LightGBM python?

Tags: python, lightgbm

I am using the `model = lgb.train` function. When trying to plot the evaluation metric against epochs of a LightGBM model (i.e., `lgb.plot_metric(model)`) I get the following error:

> TypeError: booster must be dict or LGBMModel. To use plot_metric with Booster type, first record the metrics using record_evaluation callback then pass that to plot_metric as argument `booster`

But I cannot find any info in the [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html) about parameters to set up the mentioned [callback](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.record_evaluation.html). Is there any way to implement this without resorting to the scikit-learn version of LightGBM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should help to plot the metrics. I guess the documentation isn't really clear on usage but here is an example [notebook](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/examples/python-guide/notebooks/interactive_plot_example.ipynb). The evals dictionary contains an OrderedDict and can be plotted using the `plot_metric` method.

```
train_dt = lgb.Dataset(data=train,label=train_y)
valid_dt = lgb.Dataset(data = valid, 
                       label=valid_y, 
                       reference=train_dt)

params = {
        'objective': 'regression',
        'metric': 'root_mean_squared_error',
        'num_leaves': 41,
}
evals={}
mod = lgb.train(params=params, 
                train_set = train_dt, 
                valid_sets=[train_dt, valid_dt],
                callbacks = [lgb.record_evaluation(evals)])

lgb.plot_metric(evals)
```

Answer (score -3):

I not sure about lgb.train but I sure it can work if you use LGBMClassifier